# mysql : check the content change or not

Tags: php, mysql

i want to know how to find the column value change or not

Example :

table name = exam

```
     a     b      c
    12a    32     sdf
    23s    df     fds
```

if i can search the row which c column have "fds".

Query:

```
    select * from exam where c='fds';
```

but the same time,i have to check the all the field value is change or not.

thanks in advance

Comment: Umm. They can't change, it is a simple SELECT query.

Comment: how? i dont know how to get that field changed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you want to do, but by adding another column you can keep track of when the last change occurred. Either manually on each update query or, when you alter the table, you can set the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to be the default value of the column and add an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause so it will keep track of latest update.

Comment: I agree.  You can add a timestamp to the rows to track last_updated, and then compare the model for those rows (what you select prior to committing an update) against your proposed changes to see if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Your request isn't really clear for me, what i understand is that you want to check if all columns have the same values that you want to update. If so, you can do :

```
SELECT * FROM exam WHERE a='23s' AND b='df' AND c='fds';
```

If you retrieve rows then values are unchanged else at least one of them is changed.